# Is comparison lemme required for Hanson-Wright Inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I am reading Chapter 6 of Vershynin’s book on High Dimensional probability. He proves the following theorem `Hanson-Wright’ in Theorem 6.2.1. (I am modifying it slightly to make my point succinct.)

> $\textbf{Theorem}$ Let $X=(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be a random vector with independent mean $0$ sub-Gaussian coordinates. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with $A_{ii}=0$ . Then, for every $t>0,$ we have $$P(|X^TAX|\ge t)\le 2\exp\left(-c\min\left(\frac{t^2}{K^4||A||_F^2}, \frac{t}{K^2||A||}\right)\right),$$
> where $K=\max_i ||X_i||_{\psi_2}.$

The proof basically follows by controlling the moment generating function of $X^TAX.$ To this end, one uses a decoupling argument that allows us to replace $X^TAX$ by $X^TAX’$ where $X’$ is an independent copy of $X.$ This is the step that requires each coordinate of $X_i$ To be independent. More precisely, we get
$$\mathbb{E}(\exp(\lambda X^TAX))\le \mathbb{E}\exp(4\lambda X^TAX’).$$

The next step is to compare the moment generating function of $X^TAX$ With $g^TAg’$ Where $g, g’$ are independent $N(0, I_n)$ random vector. Using the comparison we obtain $$\mathbb{E}(4\lambda X^TAX’)\le \mathbb{E}(\exp(C\lambda g^TAg’)).$$
At this point, we compute the moment generating function (it is easier in Gaussian case) and do the usual optimization over $\lambda$ To get the desired inequality.

Now my question is the following. If I have $X$ and $X’$ Independent, using that $X$ is subgaussian with norm $K,$ I can show that $\mathbb{E}(\exp(\lambda X^TAX’))\le \mathbb{E}\exp(C\lambda^2 K^2 ||AX’||_2^2)$ for some $C.$ Now I use the fact that $||AX’||_2^2\le ||A||^2||X’||^2.$ Using that coordinate of $X’$ Are independent, I can show that $||X’||^2$ is subexponential and therefore I can bound the moment generating function of $||X’||_2^2.$ I did not work out the exact constants, but it seems to me that I am getting the same inequality.

Can anyone tell me if this approach is fine? Does it give the same inequality or not? My point is to understand if comparison lemma is just a tool to better organize the proofs or it really adds something that I do not get otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you considerably overestimate with $\|AX\|\leqslant \|A\|\|X\|$. This makes the bound depend on the dimension of X. You dont want that, in fact matrix and vector are never decoupled like that in more accurate proofs.

Comment: Won't it always depend on the dimension of $X$? simply by the fact that the frobenious norm will grow with the dimension of $X$.